# Sorting SQL table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting

I am having problems with sorting a table using PHP. I just want to figure out how to make buttons from which I can sort a table by criteria without damaging the code. The criteria are to sort three columns "Price", "ArtistName" and "AlbumName" in ascending and descending order. I am looking forward to opinions and I will be thankful for any tips.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
if (!$con) {
die("Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$mysqlget = "SELECT * FROM Albums";
$mysqldata = mysqli_query($con, $mysqlget) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error($con));

echo "<table class='table_albums'>";
echo "<tr><th>Album</th><th>Description</th><th>Artist</th><th>Price</th><th colspan='2'>Additional Options</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<img class='album_artwork' src='";
echo $row['AlbumImage'];
echo "'></td><td><p class='info_album_artist'>";
echo $row['Info'];
echo "<p></td><td>";
echo "<img class='artist_artwork' src='";
echo $row['ArtistImage'];
echo "'></td><td><p class='info_album_artist'>&pound;";
echo $row['Price'];
echo "<p></td><td>";
echo "<a href='";
echo $row['MoreInfo'];
echo "' class='more_info'>More Info</a></td><td>";
echo $row['Buy'];
echo "</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: You can sort in the query. You can sort with PHP using sort(), etc. You can sort on the client if you have all the data.

Comment: depend for what you want to sort by  `"SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY Price DESC"`

Comment: Yes, I know these suggestions, but I want to implement them in the appropriate way in which an error should not occur.

Comment: @Niksan555 are you still here ?

Comment: @mkaatman _"You can sort with PHP using sort(), etc."_ that would be stupid. Databases are optimized to sort things as fast and efficiently as possible. Even quicksort can't beat a hashmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go with all options

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="sort" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option>Order by ...</option>
    <option value="price_desc">Price descending</option>
    <option value="price_asc">Price ascending</option>
    <option value="artist_name_desc">Artist Name descending</option>
    <option value="artist_name_asc">Artist Name ascending</option>
    <option value="album_name_desc">Album Name descending</option>
    <option value="album_name_asc">Album Name ascending</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php

$sort = $_POST['sort'];

if ($sort == 'price_desc')
{
    $mysqlget = "SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY Price DESC";
}
else if ($sort == 'price_asc')
{
    $mysqlget = "SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY Price ASC";
}
else if ($sort == 'artist_name_desc')
{
    $mysqlget = "SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY ArtistName DESC";
}
else if ($sort == 'artist_name_asc')
{
    $mysqlget = "SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY ArtistName ASC";
}
else if ($sort == 'album_name_desc')
{
    $mysqlget = "SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY AlbumName DESC";
}
else if ($sort == 'album_name_asc')
{
    $mysqlget = "SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY AlbumName ASC";
}
else
{
    $mysqlget = "SELECT * FROM Albums";
}

$mysqldata = mysqli_query($con, $mysqlget) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error($con));

echo "<table class='table_albums'>";
echo "<tr><th>Album</th><th>Description</th><th>Artist</th><th>Price</th><th colspan='2'>Additional Options</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<img class='album_artwork' src='";
echo $row['AlbumImage'];
echo "'></td><td><p class='info_album_artist'>";
echo $row['Info'];
echo "<p></td><td>";
echo "<img class='artist_artwork' src='";
echo $row['ArtistImage'];
echo "'></td><td><p class='info_album_artist'>&pound;";
echo $row['Price'];
echo "<p></td><td>";
echo "<a href='";
echo $row['MoreInfo'];
echo "' class='more_info'>More Info</a></td><td>";
echo $row['Buy'];
echo "</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy using SQL. Example:

Sort by Info:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY Info
```

Sort in descending order:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY Info DESC
```

---

To make buttons that sort the table, I would use GET, like:

```
<a href="?orderby=Info">Info</a>
```

PHP code:

```php
$mysqlget = 'SElECT * FROM Albums';

if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
    switch ($_GET['orderby']) {
        case 'Info':
            $mysqlget .= ' ORDER BY Info';
            break;
        case 'Artist':
            $mysqlget .= ' ORDER BY Artist';
            break;
        // ...
    }
}

$mysqldata = mysqli_query($con, $mysqlget) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error($con));
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example, thank you in advance!